# How do I replace buttons horizontally in Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new at coding. Right now I am trying to create a navbar with Bootstrap. But i cant place the buttons horizontally. I have tried `class="float-right"`  literally in every element. And i tried to ovverride with `!important` in css. Again no response. Can you help me how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGKZR.png)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups should provide enough information depending on the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, the navbar needs one of the `navbar-expand-*` classes to make it horizontal, otherwise the navbar will be vertical/mobile (the default).

Also, there is no `navbar-btn` class in Bootstrap 4. Just use `btn btn-*`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Btn</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/4mT9YOawzV